# Application Gateway to pickup new IP of AKS POD

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-application-gateway

I have a simple site running in AKS which is load balanced with an application gateway. The pod IP for the site is setup as a backend pool in the AGW but if I restart the pod, the IP changes therefor the backend pool will break.

Is there anyway AGW can pickup the POD's name rather then using its IP address, so if we do restart a pod, it will still be available in the back end pool?

Thanks

Comment: Why not use a ClusterIP service to front your pod?

Comment: Is using [AGIC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/ingress-controller-overview) an option? It can handle syncing up pod IP address changes to the gateway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank You [CSharpRocks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/793891/csharprocks) for your suggestion.

Would suggest you to use the Cluster IP to front your POD because ClusterIP cannot be changed, but External IP can.

[image]

you might lose the external IP forever; with cloud providers, for example, if you haven't reserved it previously.

You can edit the service and change the external IP, or change the service type, in which case it will lose it automatically, and change it back to `LoadBalancer` type, later on, with different IP address.

But to change the `ClusterIP` you have to delete the service.

Reference : [Can a kubernetes service change IP when rolling out/restart my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59545658/can-a-kubernetes-service-change-ip-when-rolling-out-restart-my-app)